# The value created inside the structure method/function isn't the same as the value accessed in main

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

I'm new to C, started it two days ago. Had some experience in python.

What I'm doing is creating a structure representing a 3D `Point` with (x,y,z). The values are pointers to a float. The reasons it's not a float is gonna be explained later.

I'm also creating a `Face` structure which has multiple points. The Face is a triangle, so 3 point and a center point, located at the center of the triangle. Again, it's using pointers.

Finally (in the unseen code) I'll have a 3D Object structure. It will possess a VertexMatrix, a Face_vertex_index_array and an array of pointers to the faces.

Because it uses pointers, if I translate the object, touch the individual point, or modify a point coordinate, it will apply to all.

###### The Bug

I calculate the center point of the Face, assign it a Point3D to it, assign a pointer to the face.

When I print the Point3D inside of the method, it works. When I print it in main through the pointer, it gives a default/randomly generated float as if it was never assigned.
I tried this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//---------------------------------Point3D structure.----------------------------------------
typedef struct
{
    float *x;
    float *y;
    float *z;
} Point3D; // using pointers

Point3D *print_Point3D(Point3D *point)
{
    printf("p[x y z] = [ %p %p %p ]\n", (point->x), (point->y), (point->z));
    printf("[x y z] = [ %f %f %f ]\n", *(point->x), *(point->y), *(point->z));
}

//---------------------------------PolygonFace structure----------------------------------------
typedef struct
{
    Point3D *p1;
    Point3D *p2;
    Point3D *p3;
    Point3D *center;
} PolygonFace;

PolygonFace *createPolygonFace(PolygonFace *face,
                               Point3D *pPoint1, Point3D *pPoint2, Point3D *pPoint3)
{
    face = malloc(sizeof(pPoint1) * 4);
    face->p1 = pPoint1;
    face->p2 = pPoint2;
    face->p3 = pPoint3;

    float center_x, center_y, center_z;
    center_x = center_y = center_z = 0.f;

    center_x = (*(pPoint1->x) + *(pPoint2->x) + *(pPoint3->x)) / (3.f);
    center_y = (*(pPoint1->y) + *(pPoint2->y) + *(pPoint3->y)) / (3.f);
    center_z = (*(pPoint1->z) + *(pPoint2->z) + *(pPoint3->z)) / (3.f);

    Point3D center_point = {.x = &center_x, .y = &center_y, .z = &center_z};
    face->center = &center_point;
    printf("This is the center point inside:\n");
    print_Point3D(face->center);

    return face;
}

//---------------------------------------Main-------------------------
void main()
{
    printf("----------------start of program--------------\n\n");

    float x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3;
    x2 = x3 = y1 = y3 = z1 = z2 = 0;
    x1 = y2 = z3 = 1;

    // p1 = [1, 0 ,0 ]
    // p2 = [0,1,0]
    // p3 = [0,0,1] 

    Point3D po1 = {.x = &x1, .y = &y1, .z = &z1};
    Point3D po2 = {.x = &x2, .y = &y2, .z = &z2};
    Point3D po3 = {.x = &x3, .y = &y3, .z = &z3};

    PolygonFace *face_test = createPolygonFace(face_test, &po1, &po2, &po3);

    printf("\n This is the center point\n");
    print_Point3D((face_test->center));
}
```

I got this

[image: The output inside the local function vs in main.]

[image: The variable in the debugger]

I expect them to be equal. [0.33 0.33 0.33]
The center of a triangle at î, ^j ,^k.

Comment: *Why* are you using so many pointers? Especially, why use pointers to single `float` values? The less pointers your code have, the simpler it will be. And the simpler your program is, the less chances of mistakes. And of course also it's easier to test, debug and maintain.

Comment: Case in point: `.x = &center_x` (for example). Here `center_x` is a *local* variable. It's life-time will end when the function returns. The saved pointer will be invalid. Simple solution: Don't use pointers for simple values.

Comment: Use text not images.

Comment: Because I want it to be shared. Originally, it would be inside a for loop which points to an array. Since The pace, points and the array represent the same object, I use pointers.

Comment: I'm not quite following your rational for needing pointers for everything, but you can use the `&` operator in C to "take the address of" something. For example: declare `float f`, then you can pass the address of `f` to a function like `void changeMyFloat(float* myFloat){ ... }` with `changeMyFloat(&f);`. So you can have a whole array of floats `float myFloats[100];`, pass their addresses to a function `changeMyFloat(&(myFloats[34]));` without having to `malloc` a thing.

Comment: Oh. It's because of in this Code, I have a 2D n×4 array that has actual floats stored in it. I want every thing to point to this array. It's the raw data.  It's all just to have data in a hopefully more readable form. The end goal is to simple have a reapeatable syntax. Object3D->FaceList[5]->Point3D->p1->x = float 2.7f        while it will need parenthesis, that will be simpler.

Comment: Rather then 2.7, It would be           a

Answer (score 0):

In `createPolygonFace`, you're capturing the addresses of several local variables inside of the allocated structure and returning those local pointers.  The lifetime of those addresses ends when the function exits, making the pointers invalid.  Attempting to dereference those invalid pointers triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to allocate memory for each item a pointer points to.  You also don't need the first parameter since you're overwriting the value anyway:

```
PolygonFace *createPolygonFace(Point3D *pPoint1, Point3D *pPoint2, Point3D *pPoint3)
{
    PolygonFace *face = malloc(sizeof(PolygonFace));
    face->p1 = pPoint1;
    face->p2 = pPoint2;
    face->p3 = pPoint3;

    float *center_x, *center_y, *center_z;
    center_x = malloc(sizeof(float));
    center_y = malloc(sizeof(float));
    center_z = malloc(sizeof(float));

    *center_x = (*(pPoint1->x) + *(pPoint2->x) + *(pPoint3->x)) / (3.f);
    *center_y = (*(pPoint1->y) + *(pPoint2->y) + *(pPoint3->y)) / (3.f);
    *center_z = (*(pPoint1->z) + *(pPoint2->z) + *(pPoint3->z)) / (3.f);

    Point3D *center_point = malloc(sizeof(Point3D));
    center_point->x = center_x;
    center_point->y = center_y;
    center_point->z = center_z;

    face->center = center_point;
    printf("This is the center point inside:\n");
    print_Point3D(face->center);

    return face;
}
```

Note however that your instance of `PolygonFace` contains points to some allocated objects and some pointers to local objects, and you have no way of knowing which is which.

Given how new you are to C, I would strongly recommend doing away with the pointers entirely until you have a better grasp on how they work and how to manage them.

Comment: I suggest you also mention that `print_Point3D()` should probably return nothing (void).

Comment: @AllanWind True, although it's not related to the original problem, and since the return value isn't being used it's allowable.

Comment: Ah thanks. Yeah, Well, I'm trying to learn about pointers. Also, If I didn't use pointers, the whole thing would be indexing hell by the end. As you said, there's pointers to local objects and allocated objects. So, I should allocate it all on every creation? Furthermore, C has no garbage collection, but it collects the local variable at the end of functions? Finally

Comment: God I can't new line in mobile. Ok, Finally:  why is there a * before createPolygonFace?  Similarly, Why is there a * on * Face_test = createPolygonFace(face_test)?

Comment: I found that example online and while I have an idea as to why the sintax works... I'm not sure. Same with the first malloc in createPolygonFace. It looks like it's being done before the variable is created.

Comment: @Selflearningstudent *"If I didn't use pointers, the whole thing would be indexing hell by the end"* You're going to have pointer hell which is far worse if you keep writing code like this without a deep understanding of how pointers work.  Start with simpler examples first.  You're trying to use C like it's Python, where numeric constants have an address.  Don't do that.

Comment: re: "It looks like it's being done before the variable is created." You need to understand that `sizeof` is a "compile time" operator, not a "run time" function call. The compiler replaces `sizeof x` (or `sizeof(x)` with the size (in bytes) of an object 'x'. Shown is an alternative usage (parentheses required!) to measure the size of a datatype.

Comment: Ah thanks. Also, on the pointer Hell thing. I'm kinda hoping I run into it. I'm basically trying to learn as much as I can by myself and give up at the furthest step before my next semester, where I have a C and bash course.